# 16 KB allocated by getc and fprintf on OS X

Tags: c, macos, memory-management, stdio

My application hogs memory, but does not leak it. During analysis I discovered that most of the allocated memory comes from `getc` and `fprintf` calls who do `malloc` (16kb). I did not know that those functions allocate memory on the heap? Especially `fprintf`? How can I free it?

Comment: Do they allocate at every call or just once? In the latter case, probably it's just a buffer they use for doing their duty; don't worry about it, 16 KB is *nothing* on a "normal" PC.

Comment: They are called many times, but by looking at the call graphs in valgrind the 16 KB are allocated in 1 block for every time I call a function which is involved with getc and fprintf... (16kb * many calls) == lots of memory. If it is a buffer, how can I free it?

Comment: Really, _most_ of your memory comes from `getc` and `fprintf`?

Comment: There is a distinct operation which leads to these allocations from getc and fprintf. Every one of those leads to a couple of "still reachable" 16kb blocks. Consider this: The application runs long times and it does lots and lots of said operation.

Comment: Can you explain how you're measuring this?

Comment: If your description is correct, this **is** a leak. It does mot matter that the memory is ltagged as still reachable if it cannot in fact be reused.

Comment: If you're calling them on a new stream, then of course you'll get a new buffer. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, they all have distinct streams. I close the streams after the operation though, does this not release the buffer? I have both verified the situation using valgrind memcheck and with attaching the os x memory leak tool from "instruments".

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer to this question and then accept it, so that it can be moved from the ranks of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to call fflush on the streams before closing them... (turns out my setup does not allow fflushing the streams because they are still blocked by cancelled threads...). Thanks for your help!